# PhpWord insert docx content in to another docx

Tags: laravel, docx, phpword

I work in a Laravel project. My function is generate a docx file based on form datas. I use the PhpOffice\PhpWord package for this function. I need to insert content from another docx file.

My `PHP` code:

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

$section = $phpWord->addSection();

$section->addText('Name: '.$user->name);
$section->addText('Email: '.$user->email);
$section->addText('Telefon: '.$user->tel);

// here I need to insert the content

$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');

try {
    $objWriter->save(storage_path('app/'.$document->id.'.docx'));
}
catch (Exception $e) {
}
```

Any idea how to insert a docx content into another one?